# Изменение оформления сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

Интересует возможно ли чтобы при нажатии кнопки на сайте подгружало другой цсс файл со стилями взамену старого? Типу как на сайтах есть скачок со светлой на черную тему. Буду рад если вы предложите какие-то варианты, необязательно код, можно и словами суть обьяснить

Comment: почему нет, вполне возможно, многие так и делают.. Хранят например имя темы в куках а при загрузки страницы считывают оттуда и определяют какие подгружать стили, сменился стиль - в куках записали новое значение и примерно в таком ключе..

Comment: вот вам ссылка где разобраны варианты: https://qna.habr.com/q/944881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не обязательно подгружать разные css файлы, можно просто использовать [переменные CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) и псевдокласс [`:root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:root):

```js
l = document.getElementById('l');
d = document.getElementById('d');
document.getElementsByName('style').forEach(e => e.addEventListener('change', switchTheme));

function switchTheme() {
  if (l.checked) {
    document.documentElement.className = 'light';
  } else if (d.checked) {
    document.documentElement.className = 'dark'
  } else {
    document.documentElement.className = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches ? 'dark' : 'light';
  }
}
```

```css
  :root,
:root.light {
  --bg: green;
  --text: black;
}

:root.dark {
  --bg: black;
  --text: green;
}

body {
  background: var(--bg);
  color: var(--text);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <label>
    Светлая
    <input type="radio" name="style" id="l">
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    Тёмная
    <input type="radio" name="style" id="d">
  </label>
</body>

</html>
```